# Multi-Threading with nested function in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Hi guys I've used python multiprocessing library to implement a multi-threading function for my project but I was thinking what if I nest the two functions together can I get a better performance ?

```
def subdomainsfinder(domain, threadNum=5, inputFile='/root/Gabumon/main/subdomains-top1million-5000.txt'):

    subdomains = []

    def sendRequest(sub):
        # print(sub)
        r = requests.session()
        certsh = "https://crt.sh"
        data = {"q":"%.{}.{}".format(sub, domain), "output":"json"}
        response = r.post(url = certsh, data= data)
        # print(response.text)
        ret = parseJson(response.text)

        try:
            subdomains.extend(list(ret))

        except:
            pass

    inputFile = parseFileToList(inputFile)
    pool = ThreadPool(int(threadNum))
    results = pool.map(sendRequest, inputFile)
    print(subdomains)
```

Comment: Better performance than what? Have you tried measuring the performance?

Comment: Better performance than not putting them as nested function

Comment: P.S., does `subdomainsfinder(...)` even work? For example, does it matter whether or not all of the worker threads have finished before `print(subdomains)` is called?

Comment: Yup it works , of course it matters because you want the result to shown once the threads have finished the requests

Comment: OK, so what have you done to _prevent_ `print(subdomains)` from being called before all of the tasks have been completed? I'm not a Python expert, but it looks to me as if `print(...)` will be called immediately after the last task has been submitted to the pool. How is it guaranteed that some tasks are not still awaiting replies at that point, and that other tasks are not still in the queue, not even started at that point?